# Is there a formatter plugin for .cto file for hyperledger-fabric?

Tags: visual-studio-code, hyperledger-fabric

Tried formatting .cto files in Visual Studio Code.

On using formatting shortcut - there is just a warning 'There is no formatter for 'composer' - files installed.'

Is there a formatter plugin for .cto file for hyperledger-fabric?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a formatter, but have you installed https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-vscode-plugin ?

Comment: Yes. Does not format the cto file. It just warns  'There is no formatter for 'composer' - files installed.'

Comment: I was pretty sure that was the case, but just wanted to double check.  You can always open up an issue in the Composer Github repo